# Automatically run CasperJS file from command line

Tags: command-line, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there a way to set a time when CasperJS will run that way the file can run while I'm not at my desk at the same time every night? If so how to set that up. Pretty new to using command line so help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a scripting language like Python to execute your CasperJS script.  Once you have the python script you can setup a task if you're using windows to call that script every night at the same time.

If you need help on how to run a CasperJS script using Python you can check out this video here.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Acrx-AjCo8Q&index=2&list=PLei96ZX_m9sVFBCU6PTyinHrT-4Sh0VWI